# How to set per-queue memory limits for RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have 3 applications A, B and C which use RabbitMQ, where I have queues Q1 and Q2.

1. Application A publishes messages in Q1.
2. Application B consumes messages from Q1, does some processing, and publishes other messages in Q2. B only acks the message from Q1 after it sucessfully publishes a message in Q2.
3. Application C consumes messages from Q2, does some processing and writes something into a database.

If application A publishes faster than B can consume, it will eventually fill the memory or disc of the RabbitMQ server, which [will block any clients that try to publish messages](https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html).

B is then blocked from publishing to Q2 before it can ack the message from Q1, leading to a deadlock.

If I could limit the memory and disc usage for each queue, rather than for the whole RabbitMQ, I think this could be solved.
Is there a way to do this, or another way to solve my problem?

I could switch to another message broker that supported something like this if needed.

Answer (score 1):

No, setting per-queue disc or memory limit is not what can be done in RabbitMQ (at least for now).

If messages can't be lost and are mission-critical, making application B consume with the same speed as A or faster, say, by increase consumers number may be the solution.

Another approach, is to drop extra messages, say, via [Per-Queue Message TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-queue-message-ttl) or with [Queue Length Limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html).

Sure, that messages can be [dead-lettered](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) for alarm notification and/or backup.

You can also check queue length time to time and do some heuristics to monitor that and correlate your workflow (note, `queue.declare` will return messages number in current queue but this AMQP method is idempotent by itself).

Comment: Wouldn't dead-lettering use the same space in disc?

Comment: Definitely it would, the idea is to get message from there just for alarm, say you can also set length limit to 1 on queue that dead lettered messages goes to, so only one message will stay there for alarm. It's a bit tricky, but in this way you haven't track original queue size all the time and it simple to implement.

Comment: There's also a 'x-max-length-bytes' setting for queues https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html